# Batch File Recursively Identify and Copy to Other Multiple Directories

Tags: batch-file

I need to identify all files that begin with US_ within a folder, and then copy those to multiple numbered folders.

I'm using the following code for the copy, but cannot figure out how to identify the files to be copied. %ROOTPATH% has been define previously:

```
ECHO Which workstation are you copying user settings FROM?
SET /p WSFROM="Workstation Number?: "

ECHO Enter a range (eg. 5, eg. 10-15)
SET /p WSTO="Workstation Numbers?: "

for /f "usebackq delims=- tokens=1,2" %%a in ('%WSTO%') do (
    set "LOWERWS=%%a"
    set "UPPERWS=%%b"
)

if not "%UPPERWS%"=="" goto :copy_range

:copy_range
FOR /L %%i IN (%LOWERWS%, 1, %UPPERWS%) DO (
xcopy %ROOTPATH%\WORKSTATIONS\%WSFROM%\US_*.DAT %ROOTPATH%\WORKSTATIONS\%%i\US_*.DAT %%G)
```

Comment: What's `%%G` ?  And what exactly is the task to be done?  Take note that 4th line from the end is redundant because it will always execute `:copy_range`

Comment: That %%G is a typo. I don't know why it's there. And I plan to put some code inbetween that's why the     :copy_range call is there. What needs to be done is identify all the files in that directory with the prefix US_, and copy them to other folders that are numbered and already existing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line should work with your code:

```
xcopy "%ROOTPATH%\WORKSTATIONS\%WSFROM%\US_*.DAT" "%ROOTPATH%\WORKSTATIONS\%%i\"
```

Comment: Guess I probably should have played around with my code a little longer before giving up huh...works like a charm. Thanks @foxidrive :)